# what is the equivalent of rdf:ID in RDFlib?

Tags: python, syntax, rdf, rdflib

I tried `g.add(foo,RDF.ID,boo)`
but it didn't work.
In the other hand `RDF.type` and `RDF.about` seems to work.
how can i use rdf:ID in rdflib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `rdf:ID` is not an RDF property (neither is `rdf:about`, by the way), it's merely a syntactical device of the RDF/XML syntax. Just like angle brackets `<` and `>` are syntactical devices.

In RDF/XML, `rdf:ID` is used to identify the subject of one or more RDF statements. For example:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:ID="p1">
      <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Person">
      <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
</rdf:Description>
```

is a bit of RDF/XML that contains two RDF statements. The subject for both of these statements is `p1`. The first statement says that `p1` is of type `Person`. The second statement says that the label of `p1` is "John".

The trick, when working with RDFLib or any other RDF tool, is to think in terms of the RDF graph (that is, the collection of statements). Forget you ever saw what RDF/XML looked like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. is this the same thing with `JSON-LD`? I mean the `@id` is also a syntactical device for the `JSON-LD`?

Comment: Yes. It is. Btw here on SO, if an answer has been helpful to you, vote on it, or even mark it as accepted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers